# Как в SQLite сделать сложный запрос с циклом

Tags: c#, sqlite

Есть список из имен, нужно для каждого имени сделать запрос

```
UPDATE [dbUserTable] SET [IsOnline] = 0 WHERE [IsOnline] = 1
```

Я это делаю с цикле

```
public async Task UpdateOnlineStatus(List<string> Names)
{
using (SQLiteConnection Connect = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data 
Source=TestDB.db; Version=3;"))
{
    string SQL = "UPDATE [dbUserTable] SET [IsOnline] = 1 WHERE [Name] = @Name";
    Connect.Open();
    using (SQLiteCommand Command = new SQLiteCommand(SQL, Connect))
    {
        foreach (string Name in Names)
        {
            speedtest++;
            Command.Parameters.Clear();
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
            await Command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
         }
     }
     Connect.Close();
}
}
```

Но это очень медленно работает. Можно в SQLite это все сделать одним запросом ? По типу этого

```
            int length = Names.Count;
            SQL = $"DECLARE @list VARCHAR({length}) DECLARE @i INTEGER " +
                "SET @i=0 " +
                "SET @list = @Names" +
                $"WHILE (@i <= {length} - 1 " +
                "BEGIN " +
                    "UPDATE [dbUserTable] SET [IsOnline] = @IsOnline WHERE [Name] = @list(@i) " +                        
                    "SET @i = @i + 1) " +
                "END";
            Connect.Open();
            using (SQLiteCommand Command = new SQLiteCommand(SQL, Connect))
            {
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Names", Names);
                var test = await Command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            Connect.Close();
```

Comment: что такое `очень медленно работает`? Вы там миллионы записей обновляете? Если так, то глядите в сторону Bulk операций.

Comment: Нет, не миллионы. Тысячи. И на 1к записей уходит примерно 3 минуты, при этом другие потоки не могут достучаться до бд т.к. она занята и выходит исключение database is locked

Comment: Стандартная практика с Sqlite: обернуть запросы в одну транзакцию. Другой способ: `where in (...)`. Позже подробно распишу, если никто ещё не ответит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В SQLite каждый запрос оборачивается в транзакцию, что сильно замедляет выполнение множества запросов.
В Frequently Asked Questions есть пункт про [INSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19) - нужно обернуть несколько запросов в одну транзакцию.
Благодаря этому вставка ста тысяч строк выполняется менее чем за секунду.

```
public void InsertData()
{
    var sql = "INSERT INTO [dbUserTable] ([IsOnline], [Name]) values (@isonline, @name);";

    using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=TestDB.db; Version=3;"))
    using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var tran = conn.BeginTransaction())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("isonline", DbType.Int32).Value = 0;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("name", DbType.String).Value = "Name" + i;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            tran.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

К сожалению, это не помогает при выполнении UPDATE и DELETE.
Также к сожалению, в SQLite нет табличных параметров (table-valued parameters). Обычно с их помощью в других СУБД выполняются такие запросы.

Можно поступить так:

```
public async Task UpdateOnlineStatus(List<string> names)
{
    var parameters = string.Join(",", names.Select((_, i) => "@p" + i));
    string sql = $"UPDATE [dbUserTable] SET [IsOnline] = 1 WHERE [Name] IN ({parameters})";

    using (var connect = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=TestDB.db; Version=3"))
    using (var command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connect))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("p" + i, DbType.String).Value = names[i];
        }
        await connect.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Здесь формируется длинный список параметров `@p0,@p1,@p2` для использования в `WHERE IN`.
Конечно, очень длинный список использовать не стоит.
Я попробовал этот код с десятью тысячами значений - проблем не возникло.
Выполнение запроса с 10000 параметров на моей системе выполняется менее, чем за 2 секунды. Это с SSD. С HDD наверняка будет несколько медленней.

---

Действительно, если попытаться задать 50 тысяч параметров, то выбрасывается исключение:

> SQL logic error too many SQL variables

В sqlite есть ограничение [Maximum Number Of Host Parameters In A Single SQL Statement](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_variable_number), которое по умолчанию равно 999 для версий до 3.32.0 или 32766 для версий после 3.32.0.
Также есть ограничение [Maximum Length Of An SQL Statement](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_sql_length), равное миллиарду байтов, но оно нам вряд ли грозит.

Естественно, желательно пользоваться самой новой версией Sqlite. Впрочем это не поможет обойти порог в 32766 параметров.
Как это можно обойти?

Конечно, можно разбивать один большой запрос на несколько более мелких, с количеством параметров не более 32766. Код писать не буду, думаю, каждый желающий сам справится.

Предложу ещё одно решение, с временной таблицей.

```
public async Task UpdateOnlineStatus(List<string> names)
{
    using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=TestDB.db; Version=3;"))
    {
        await conn.OpenAsync();

        var createSql = "CREATE TEMP TABLE [params] ([Name] text)";
        using (var createCmd = new SQLiteCommand(createSql, conn))
        {
            await createCmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }

        var insertSql = "INSERT INTO [params] ([Name]) values (@name)";
        using (var insertCmd = new SQLiteCommand(insertSql, conn))
        {
            var nameParam = insertCmd.Parameters.Add("name", DbType.String);
            using (var tran = conn.BeginTransaction())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
                {
                    nameParam.Value = names[i];
                    await insertCmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                }
                tran.Commit();
            }
        }

        var updateSql = "UPDATE [dbUserTable] SET [IsOnline] = 1 WHERE [Name] IN (SELECT [Name] FROM [params])";
        using (var updateCmd = new SQLiteCommand(updateSql, conn))
        {
            await updateCmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Что здесь происходит. Открываем соединение - вся дальнейшая работа происходит с ним.
Создаём **временную** таблицу: CREATE **TEMP** TABLE.
В рамках одной транзакции в эту таблицу вставляем параметры. Это, как мы уже знаем, происходит очень быстро.
Далее выполняем запрос `UPDATE` с использованием этой временной таблицы.

Проверил на 50 тысячах параметров. Работает очень быстро. Думаю, это лучший вариант.

---

Примечания.

Вы используете библиотеку `System.Data.SQLite`, это понятно по именам `SQLiteConnection`, `SQLiteCommand`. Я бы предложил попробовать провайдер `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` - более новый и легковесный (по заверениям разработчиков). Возможно, он будет чуть быстрее.
Но это в любом случае несущественно.

Sqlite не поддерживает асинхронный I/O. [Async limitations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/async). Поэтому нет смысла в вызове асинхронных методов.

Comment: Спасибо! Вообще очень интересно про insert с BeginTransaction. Я на импорт своей бд в sqlite убил несколько часов....

Comment: Может есть 3й способ? С большим количеством значений происходит исключение "SQL logic error
too many SQL variables". Или тут уже стоит использовать SQL классик?

Comment: @user2213608 - сколько именно значений?

Comment: примерно от 50000 до 70000

Comment: @user2213608 - обновил ответ

Comment: не уверен писать сюда или создать отдельный вопрос по mysql. в mysql запрос
 var updateSql = $"UPDATE {_DbName}.dbUserTable SET IsOnline = 1 WHERE Name IN (SELECT Name FROM {_DbName}.params)"; 
выполняется очень медленно. На столько медленно, что он не может за 30 секунд его выполнить и выдает исключение Fatal error encountered during command execution.  для mysql надо делать как-то по другому ?

Comment: @user2213608 - лучше задать новый вопрос отдельно